# Non blocking IO and HystrixObservableCommand

Tags: java, jetty, nonblocking, hystrix, asynchttpclient

I understand that

1. There are benefits of using [hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix) to wrap dowstream service calls.
2. Also, there are several advantages of using non-blocking IO to call downstream services. (especially in my application, which is typically kind of a proxy server)
3. Also, hystrix has [HystrixObservableCommand](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hystrixoss/g7ZLIudE8Rs) that can be used for non-blocking paradigms.
4. Also, java has few libraries that can make non-blocking http calls - [Jetty Http Client](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/http-client.html), [AsynHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client)
5. ***But*** I am unaware of any java library that does http calls and returns Observable, so that it can be wrapped in a HystrixObservableCommand.

Is having an Observable for http calls the right pattern? Is there any library that is suitable for this?

Answer (score 2):

```
Also, hystrix has HystrixObservableCommand that can be used for non-blocking paradigms.
```

I would say this sentence is not accurate, Observable is about streaming and actually it is blocking by default. It gives you easy way to make it concurrent, but still, you have to do it yourself.

So you don't need to look for a library which return Observable result for http request, instead do it yourself and wrap the result with observable.

checkout this post for wrapping http requests with Observable

[Make Http call using ReactiveX for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449904/make-http-call-using-reactivex-for-java)